# Adding LinearLayout to a LinearLayout in android

Tags: android

I have found lots of question here regarding adding `LinearLayout` dynamically. I haven't found any reference or any tutorial or books suggested where I could know complete details of the and steps to add a `LinearLayout` dynamically.

```
    LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.master);
    LinearLayout Linear1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    Linear1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    Linear1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    parentLayout.addView(Linear1);
```

This is the code snippet I am using for adding a Layout. The problem is that the min api required is 11. I have designed my app targeting api 10. So its very bad news for me. Please tell me is there any other way to add `LinearLayout` dynamically for the lower apis?

**Error Message:**  Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): new android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams

Comment: What errors are you getting when you do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong `LayoutParams` class. Use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `ActionBar.LayoutParams`.

Comment: That doesn't compute; I don't see any references to ActionBar in the code snippet.  OP, you're going to need to show us the actual code. But yeah, Ahmad is right; ActionBar is not available prior to API 11 so don't use it. Your IDE should have flagged this.

Comment: @EdwardFalk: I pressed ctrl+shift+o and by default the editor imported the `ActionBar.layoutpParams` class after seeing @Ahmad 's answer I checked my import statements and found that I have imported wrong class. I have corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, add following line in the import section:

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
```