# How to create a linear layout with textview and image button dynamically

Tags: android

i want to create a linear layout where inside it it has text view and image button. And i want to create it dynamically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding LinearLayout to a LinearLayout in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868687/adding-linearlayout-to-a-linearlayout-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinearLayout layoutSection = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
params.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
TextView textView = newTextView(getActivity());
TextView.setText(("Enter text here");
layoutSection.addView(textView);
layoutSection.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. But how can i change the orientation of the linear layout?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661261/how-to-add-dynamic-content-to-lineary-layout-programmatically-in-my-case